# React Native - Microphone voice waves

Tags: react-native, microphone, voice

I am currently implementing an audio recorder in the app I am working on.
Everything works great, but I cannot find a way to capture the sound waves of the microphone, which would make the app look even better.
Do any one of you guys know a library that I could use, or a Native solution to find these values? I can make the animations myself.

Comment: Do you mean that you need help setting the recording process or do you mean that you have recording process set up and you would like to represent the recording as a wave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very easy, there is a library called hark which can help you to listen to audio streams and emit events (speaking / not speaking)

Here is the library link with NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hark

Example:

```
import hark from 'hark';

var speech = hark(stream, options); // stream is the sound coming from user's mic
speech.on('speaking', function() {
   setSpeaking(true);
});

speechEvents.on('stopped_speaking', function() {
  setSpeaking(false);
});
```